# How to use params flag for muliple values with comma seperated when executing pig job on google dataproc?

Tags: parameters, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

How can I pass multiple values with comma separated for one key.

**Command1:**

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig--cluster msm-test-cluster -e "set;" --properties foo=bar --params bar=baz,bar1=(f1:chararray)
```

**Command2:**

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig--cluster msm-test-cluster -e "set;" --properties foo=bar --params bar=baz,bar1=(f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:chararray)
```

In the above command1 running fine but command2 bar1 having multiple values with comma-separated, it's failing because of comma between chararray and f2. How to escape this comma. See the below error message. If anyone knows the solution please let me know.

```
**ERROR:** (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pig) argument --params: Bad syntax for dict arg: [id:chararray)]. Please see `gcloud topic flags-file` or `gcloud topic escaping` for information on providing list or dictionary flag values with special characters.
Usage: gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig --cluster=CLUSTER (--execute=QUERY, -e QUERY | --file=FILE, -f FILE) [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --async | --bucket | --continue-on-failure |
                         --driver-log-levels | --execute | --file | --help |
                         --jars | --labels | --max-failures-per-hour |
                         --params | --properties | --region
```

For detailed information on this command and its flags,

```
run:gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig --help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue should be resolved using the gcloud escaping technique. Reference link : [GCloud Escaping](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping)

So the command could be updated and executed as below:

gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig--cluster msm-test-cluster -e "set;" --properties foo=bar --params **^~^bar1="(f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:chararray)"~bar=baz**

Answer (score 1):

As the [Cloud SDK Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pig) suggests, you would need to encapsulate any comma-separated key-vlaue pairs inside `[ ]`. Therefore, re-writing the `gcloud` command like such should work:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig--cluster msm-test-cluster -e "set;" --properties foo=bar --params=[bar=baz,bar1=(f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:chararray)]
```

Comment: I have tried with below commad still it's failing with the below error.                                                   gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig--cluster msm-test-cluster -e "set;" --properties foo=bar --params=[bar=baz,bar1=(f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:chararray)]

ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pig) argument --params: Bad syntax for dict arg: [f2:chararray]. Please see `gcloud topic flags-file` or `gcloud topic escaping` for information on providing list or dictionary flag values with special characters.