# gcloud cloud run - set a custom domains Integration with multi domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I use `gcloud` beta version.

I want set a integration as kind of  `Custom Domains - Google Cloud Load Balancing` with multi domain.

I have a problem with the syntax of the command.

In load balancer, SSL certificate can be built to support multiple domains.
So, How to create a integration with multi domain mapping?

sample command:

```
gcloud beta run integrations create --type=custom-domains --region=us-central1 --parameters='set-mapping=domain1.com:serviceName'
```

In this image, you can see that it is possible to define with several domains:

[image]

The GCP document links:

1. [gcloud beta run integrations create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/integrations/update?authuser=1)
2. [Map custom domains using a global external HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/integrations/update?authuser=1)

Please visit this question in google cloud community:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/gcloud-cloud-run-set-a-custom-domains-Integration-with-multi/m-p/512687#M1061

Comment: Create a HTTPS Load Balancer in GCC

Reserve a static IP address for the LB.

Obtain or create an SSL certificate that covers all of the domains.

Upload the certificate to Google Cloud.

Map each domain to a separate backend service using the load balancer's IP address as the target.

Configure your domain registrar to map each domain to the reserved IP address using a CNAME or A record.

Verify that each domain resolves to the correct IP address by using the "nslookup" command

Test each custom domain by accessing it in a web browser to ensure that it resolves to your LB.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I took a look at the question in the google cloud community and the GCP documents you linked and I think I know what the issue is.</s>

In your first link under the synopsis. The parameters are a list of key value pairs.

```
    [--parameters=[PARAMETER=VALUE,…]]
```

What you posted in the in the google cloud community

```
--parameters='set-mapping=domain1.com:serviceName,domain2.com:serviceName'
```

You never defined the parameter name for domain2. It should look like this.

```
--parameters='set-mapping=domain1.com:serviceName,set-mapping=domain2.com:serviceName'
```

Hope that helps you.

I looked more into this and it looks like the reason the command wasn't working was because `:` was being used a separator for the values and the whole key-value pair, which was confusing the command.

Example

```
--parameter'parameter1=value1:parameter2=value2'
```

Can also be used like this

```
--parameter'parameter1=value1:value2'
```

In order to get around this you need to use [escape characters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping).

```
gcloud beta run integrations create --type=custom-domains --region=us-central1 --parameters='^~^set-mapping="(example.com/*:myservice1,example2.com/*:myservice2)"~'
```

More info on [escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57972511/10231120).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, but it only creates the certificate with `domin2.com`